# Why won't this list of strings sort correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make high score list, which contains the a player's name and score. The score is always Why won't this sort?

```
>>>c = [' 86.3669 steve', '-100.2411 harry', ' 88.8829 lloyd']
>>>c.sort()
>>>c
[' 86.3669 steve', ' 88.8829 lloyd', '-100.2411 harry']
```

Comment: string sorting is based on character ascii value, and `-` character has higher ascii value than ` ` character.

Comment: Because a space sorts before a `-`, and `6` sorts before `8`. You are sorting *lexicographically*, or as some call it, [*ASCIIbetical*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sort doesn't convert parts of the values to numbers and compare them, it compares character by character, and as it happens space sorts before dash.